# Externally triggered high impedance toggle for large number of parallel lines

Tags: memory, bus, sram

First, I want to apologize for my terminology here -- I'm a software engineer rather than EE and I'm a bit rusty.

I have a parallel SRAM chip that is being shared by 2 CPUs that requires 19 address lines and 16 data lines. This setup is a producer-consumer model, where 1 CPU only writes, and the other CPU only reads, and they trigger interrupts on each other through an external pin to signal that the data is ready to be read/is done being read. I'm sending about 40KB of memory every 20ms, and the consumer device requires a 100ns response time for reads.

Both CPUs are therefore using the same bus. I am able to set the producer CPU's pins to high impedance through software during reads, but the "consumer" CPU doesn't support that (and in-fact I have little control over it -- it isn't even aware that there is a producer, it just thinks it is reading a standard ROM chip). So, I need the "producer" CPU to be able to set all of those lines from the "consumer" CPU to high impedance during writes (basically implementing the OE functionality on memory chips) otherwise, my understanding is that my writes will be lost since the other CPU will act as a short circuit even if all address and data lines are set to low during the write.

What type of component do I use to add tri-state support to existing bus lines while breadboarding this out? Are there options that don't require wiring up a component for each line (say, a large switchboard that I can turn all lines "off" with a single input)?

Thanks

Comment: what's the speed this runs at?

Comment: If you are by any chance building a ROM emulator, these can be bought already.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've added some timing info (50KB every 20ms, 100ns response time).

Comment: @Justme That's exactly what I'm building but I'm having difficulty finding what I need (64k, 16-bit parallel).

Comment: Classical X-Y problem. You want to do X, and have determined it can be solved with Y, so you ask help how to do Y, while you should be saying you are trying to do X and ask how to do X. Just google for EPROM emulators.

Comment: @cratonica just to get this straight: you're not actually updating the SRAM while the reader isn't reading, you're letting the "writer" react to read requests, *instead* of an actual SRAM chip.

Comment: @Justme looking at the emulators I can find, I'm not sure that satisfy my requirements. I need to read 40kb of data every 20ms from the same addresses, and that data is different every time. Most of the EPROM emulators I'm seeing still require multiple seconds of programming, but I can keep looking.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry for being unclear. I'm copying 40KB of data into the SRAM chip every 20ms, but can't have interference on the address lines from the consumer chip during this time. Once I'm doing copying the data, I allow the consumer access to the bus using $SOME_COMPONENT that allows me to enable output from the consumer chip again.

Comment: You want a form of dual port ram. Look at something like 74HC157 for the address mux and 74HC245 for the data bus.  Other parts of interest might be 74HC244,573,574.

Comment: @Kartman thank you, that is exactly what I'm looking for. To clarify: that first comment is describing what I'm building not an additional part I need? I can't find any parallel dual-port ram unfortunately (which is reasonable, since there would be a lot of pins needed for that..).

Comment: Logically it is a ‘dual port ram’. You can get dual port ram devices, but they tend to be expensive and probably not in the memory size you require. So that means you build one out of a number of chips.

Comment: One can use also VHDL and FPGA devices ... https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/programmable/support-resources/design-examples/horizontal/vhd-true-dual-port-ram-sclk.html or this https://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2017/11/vhdl-code-for-dual-port-ram-with.html or this http://www.asic-world.com/examples/vhdl/ram_dp_sr_sw.html

Comment: @Kartman do you want to provide your comment as the answer?

Comment: @Antonio51 Thank you -- that might work as well if I can find any in stock.

Comment: The comment was a product recommendation and I need to limit my reputation.

Comment: @Kartman do you think a CPLD be a suitable stand-in for those parts given the number of smaller components I'd need to wire together? I just started reading about these tonight and it seems like a much easier path vs wiring all this up by hand...

Comment: The problem is you’ll need a big cpld simply due to all the connections. Your choice of cpld is rather limited if you want 5V logic. In short, i don’t think it would be a good use of the cpld resources. You still need to wire all those address and data wires - the interconnects for the chips are the easy part. Back in the day there was little choice!

Comment: @cratonica When you say that it requires the data *from the same addresses* every 20 ms then this sounds VERY MUCH like standard VRAM used in any common, ordinary video display running at 50 Hz refresh. Like the ancient CGA, EGA and VGA, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical way to do this is with Tri-state bus buffer ICs such as the 74xx244 or 74xx541 (where xx is LS, HC, HCT, LVC etc.), which have 8 buffers enabled by 1 or 2 control inputs. To do 19 address lines you would need 3 of them. Buffer ICs with more bits are also available (such as the [74ACT16244](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/74act16244.pdf) which has 16 bits) but for various reasons it might be better to stick with 'standard' 8 bit ICs. If you only need a few more then adding an IC with fewer buffers (eg. 74xx125 which has 4 buffers) may be sufficient to get the total number you need.

If there are other devices on the 'consumer' data bus then you will probably also need Tri-state buffers on the data lines. For this you could use two 8 bit buffer ICs or a single 16 bit buffer IC.